# Why is Windows Command Prompt printing "^B" after running executable?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Something changed recently with the Windows Command Prompt on my Windows 10 machine, and it is now printing a large amount of "^B" characters after we run an executable from the command line. The executable is a compiled Fortran program and we have run it many times in the past without this issue. But now we have this carat-B pattern that is clogging my terminal every time I make a run. (see below)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of resolving this issue? I can't find anything on the internet.

[image]

Comment: does it occur only after you run that specific exe file, or does it happen with any exe files?

Comment: Just that particular .exe, none others.

Comment: it's too broad. You need to provide more information in order for someone to understand and answer this. And if there's no source code then it's off-topic here and should be on superuser.com/